# Authenticate Web App using Application Pool

Tags: iis, windows-authentication, application-pool, applicationpoolidentity

Can we authenticate an Web Application hosted on ISS with Application Identity instead of Windows Authentication.

The Application will have Windows Authentication disabled and Anonymous enabled and the application should be authenticated as with the credentials entered in Application Pool identity.

Answer (score 0):

If so you should just set anonymous authentication user to Application pool identity.
[image]

Then authenticate the Login user with your code.